# useEffect keeps rerendering a component even without an update

Tags: reactjs

Please help I'm new to react. I'm trying to create a simple messaging app.

I want MessageForm component to slightly rerender when there is an update to [messages]. it does that but doesn't stop even when there's no update.

And i know this because when i check my redux dev tools i keep seeing one action repeatedly

```
const MessageForm = ({ getMessages, addMessages, deleteMessages, messages, roomId,}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getMessages(roomId);
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [messages]);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    text: "",
  });

  const { text } = formData;

  let messagesEnd;
  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addMessages(text, roomId);
    setFormData({ text: "" });
  };

  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  let messageList = messages.messages.map((message) => {
    return message.user === user._id ? (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="container darker col-6" key={message._id}>
          <div className="username"> {message.name}</div>
          <Avatar
            size="50"
            round={true}
            src={message.avatar}
            className="right"
          />
          <p>{message.text.toString()}</p>
          <span className="time-left">
            {moments(message.createdAt).format("LLL")}
          </span>
          <span className="time-right">
            <Icon
              onClick={() => {
                deleteMessages(message._id);
              }}
              name="trash alternate"
              className="trashCan"
            />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="row justify-content-end">
        <div className="container darker senders col-6 " key={message._id}>
          <div className="username"> {message.name}</div>
          <Avatar
            size="50"
            round={true}
            src={message.avatar}
            className="right"
          />
          <p>{message.text.toString()}</p>
          <span className="time-left">
            {moments(message.createdAt).format("LLL")}
          </span>
          <span className="time-right">
            <Icon
              onClick={() => {
                deleteMessages(message._id);
              }}
              name="trash alternate"
              className="trashCan"
            />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="messageArea">
      <div className="textarea">
        {messageList}
        <div
          style={{ float: "left", clear: "both" }}
          ref={(el) => {
            messagesEnd = el;
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>

      <form className="row inputBox" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="col-10">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Message"
            aria-label="Enter Message"
            aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
            id="text"
            value={text}
            name="text"
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addMessages: (text, roomId) => dispatch(addMessages(text, roomId)),
  getMessages: (roomId) => dispatch(getMessages(roomId)),
  deleteMessages: (id) => dispatch(deleteMessages(id)),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  messages: state.messages,
  roomId: props.location.state.roomId,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MessageForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. You are calling `getMessages`, a method that probably updates `messages` both are props, and if one changes the entire component will update. useEffect doesn't control the parent component, so every time the parent updates so will the children.
2. The Second issues is that you calling a method in `useEffect` that will reload `messages`, then it will call `useEffect` again.

I would fix this by moving `getMessages` out of this component, or I would put an if statement in `useEffect` to see if you need to call `getMessages`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @nzajt's answer, maybe you don't need to use 'messages' as a dependency to your useEffect. Just treat it as a componentDidMount

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getMessages(roomId);
    scrollToBottom();
  }, []);
```

This way it wouldn't re-render indefinitely, but you wouldn't get any more updates after the first render.
If you are looking for something in real-time, take a look at something with websockets, setting up listeners or maybe make your getMessages function run every few seconds.